# How to refer a struct member value within itself?

Tags: c++, c, struct, initialization

Say I have the following simple struct in C/C++:

```c
struct Example {
    int member_a;
    int member_b;
}
```

Now, I have an object `ex` of it.
For the sake of redundancy and properly relating some members, I need to assign member_b using the value of member_a. Here, as I knew the name of this object, something like this worked for me:

```c
struct Example ex = {
    .member_a = 50,                 
    .member_b = ex.member_a * 2    // Assigning member_b in terms of member_a.
}
```

The above assignment works as long as `int member_a` is kept above `int member_b` in the declaration of Example struct.

I have already tried using `.member_b = member_a ...` and `.member_b = .member_a ...`, both of which failed to identify the member_a in a struct object. `.member_b = <same_object_name>.member_a` only seems to work with the initial definition.

Note: This all has been tried on version C18

It was a way out in case of this single struct object, but what if I do not want to use object name or if in case I'm using anonymous (unnamed) struct object? Can something like pointers or some equivalent of `this` exists that is compatible with C for using the relation in an object (or better if possible in struct definition itself)? Even being able to call a value of member like `.member_a` within Example struct shall do.

Update: If C and C++ vary a lot, please focus on a **C** specific solution.

Comment: Do I miss something, what is C/C++, a new programming language?

Comment: *"in C/C++"* -- based on the rest of your question, I think you mean "that has to be valid in both C and C++" (which is challenging since the two languages have different rules for initialization).

Comment: Re “This all has been tried on version C18”: Even if you tried it, it may behave differently in different circumstances. The behavior of the code shown is not defined by the C standard. C 2018 6.7.9 says “The evaluations of the initialization list expressions are indeterminately sequenced with respect to one another and thus the order in which any side effects occur is unspecified.” This means `ex.member_a` may be used before it is initialized. Aside from resulting in an unspecified value, that may be undefined behavior per C 2018 6.3.2.1 2.

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ are two completely different languages if they're used modernly where C++ can take advantage of classes and the this keyword. I would assume that you want to use structs in C++ for this exact question.

If you want to just have a direct relationship for example member b is twice member, then just set them equal in the original class so that it happens during compile time.

```
struct Example {
int member_a;
int member_b = 2 * member_a;
};
```

Otherwise you have to explicitly site which struct you are using when accessing ints within it. In this case a struct doesn't have any members that strictly pertain to it and the compiler doesn't know if there's going to be a value at member_a. If you wanted to use a class then you would just set it at anytime to itself, with a function or set statement.

```
class Bob {
public:
    int member_a;
    int member_b;
private:
    int double_member_a(){
    member_b = 2 * member_a;    
    return member_b
    };
};

Bob bob;

bob.member_a = 1;
bob.member_b = bob.member_a; // or bob.doubleA();
```

Regardless of the method you would still be changing a struct or classes values depending on that exact instance of the object so you would always have to state which one, though if you were going through any x struct of class you would just put them into a vector and do a range based for loop and access one at anytime.